# Decision Tree with no pruning in R

Tags: r, decision-tree, pruning

I would like to build a decision tree with no pruning at all. 
As can be seen in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136683/is-rpart-automatic-pruning) using default `rpart` also prunes the decision tree. Does using the value for `cp=-1` avoid pruning at all?

Comment: [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/105225) also provides information on this question.

Comment: Thanks, in his answer he is not so confident about cp=-1. Is there a confident way to assure there is no pruning at all?